# Override a default property value in an inherited class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

Suppose I have the following parent class defined:

```
Public Class Parent

    Public Property Prop1 As String = "MyDB1"

End Class
```

And I wish to inherit it, but want that property to have a different value for the child class.

I figured I could do it as follows:

```
Public Class Child
    Inherits Parent

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        MyBase.Prop1 = "MyDB2"
    End Sub

End Class
```

But I was wondering if this was the best way to do this or if there is something like an Overridable property OR if this is just bad programming practice as a whole?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of the question, but have you tried making the property Overridable?

Comment: How about redeclaring the Property in the child class?  `Public Property Prop1 = "MyDB2"` (first using the Overridable a la @sellmeadog)

Comment: Thanks, @sellmeadog ... I just did that and it seems to work just fine too! - I guess my question is whether that is better or worse or just different from what I did? I'm still trying to learn best programming practices for OOP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, here's my opinion:

- If you are in control of the base class, make it `Overridable` if the intent is to have it's value change based on business rule(s) of the derived type(s)
- If you are not in control of the base class, and you need to "override" the property, you can "hide" the base property; in C#, it would look something like `new public int MyProperty { ... }` but I'm not sure how this is accomplished in VB
- If all you need is for the property to return a different value, then what you've done seems fine

Answer (score 3):

in c# for letting a property to be overridable you can mark class member as `virtual` and vb.net equvale of this keyword is `Overridable`.

```
public virtual int MyProperty {get;set;}
```

this property can be overrided in sub class like this :

```
 public override int MyProperty {
  get{ 
         //return some other thing
     }
  }
```

**Vb.NET equivalent :**

in super class :

```
 Public Overridable Property MyProperty As Integer
        Get

        End Get

        Set

        End Set

    End Property
```

and in the sub class :

```
  Public Overrides Property MyProperty As Integer
        Get
                //return some other thing
        End Get

    End Property
```

Comment: Thanks alot Behnam, makes perfect sense and thanks for the code samples!!! - I only didn't mark you as a solution (although it is perfectly right) because @sellmeadog provided the solution sooner. Thanks SO MUCH, though!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos thanks !but i were 8 min earlier than sellmeadog.anyway... :)

Comment: Your solution, yes, but we were already discussing it via the comments... Sorry, man, I was just trying to be fair to him :)